# Read an image in specified interval with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

There is a file on the network and it will be refreshed every 50 millisecond, I want to read it every 50ms, it's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int c;
    IplImage *img;
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("http://192.168.1.3:8020/image.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 5, 5);
    while(1)
    {
        img=cvQueryFrame(capture);
        cvShowImage("mainWin", img );
        c=cvWaitKey(10);
        if(c == 27)
        break;
    }
 return 0;

}
```

but this code read it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cvCaptureFromFile is for readign from video files, if you pass it a single image it assumes it can't change so always returns the same image

I don't know if cvLoadImage will read from a URL in your version of openCV but try:

```
cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 5, 5);
while(1)
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("http://192.168.1.3:8020/image.jpg");
    img=cvQueryFrame(capture);
    cvShowImage("mainWin", img );
    c=cvWaitKey(10);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
 }
```